# PuTTY Software caused connection error - file transferring

Tags: php, ssh, server, putty

I have a PHP script, which takes a zip file from another server, processes it and puts some data into .xml files. I run the script via SSH connection, using PuTTY app. Now the problem I guess is that it takes too long to process all the files and PuTTY aborts the script, or there can be possibly another problem? I don't see any error or something.

I get the error after arround an hour from the beginning of it.

Comment: Did you try enabling keepalives? https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-keepalive

Comment: Yes, I set it to 10 seconds, still same disconnect.

Comment: Did you try modifying the script to report some progress to keep the connection busy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that the problem was the server memory limit. It wasn't enough memory to process all these files so it crashed. Thank you.